# Rails money round cents up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

I'm trying to round my money without cents, but I want the amount to be rounded up always (ceil).

I've done:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|
  config.rounding_mode = BigDecimal::ROUND_CEILING
end

Money.new(12345).format(:no_cents)
```

But it still returns "$123" instead of "$124".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking through the Money gem and format doesn't appear to leverage any rounding rules. Its just chopping off cents to get an "absolute" value.

```
formatted = self.abs.to_s
...
if rules[:no_cents] || (rules[:no_cents_if_whole] && cents % currency.subunit_to_unit == 0)
  formatted = "#{formatted.to_i}"
end
```

Source here: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/master/lib/money/money/formatting.rb

Tried to find a work around for you, maybe add this as a method to your Rails Model:

```
[2] pry(main)> require 'money'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> money = Money.new(12345, 'USD')
=> #<Money fractional:12345 currency:USD>
[6] pry(main)> "#{money.currency.symbol}#{money.to_f.ceil}"
=> "$124"
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing something similar to this.

Comment: NP! Can you mark this as answer if it resolved the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it doesn't actually solve the issue, that's why I didn't mark it. It's more like a workaround.
But since there's no way to do it that isn't a workaround I'll mark it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the rounding mode to `ROUND_UP`, rather than `ROUND_CEILING`?

Comment: Yes, to the same result

Comment: Weird! Sorry, I know it's a simple thing and you probably did, but did you restart your server after changing the config?

Comment: Yep, I've restarted it. Evn tried it again to be sure.